# How to lock serialization in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

I am just starting with Java serialization: I have one exercise to do and I need to lock serialization on any class, it is suppose to throw an exception when I attempt to serialize that class.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Just for one class, or for *any* class you try to serialize?

Answer (score 5):

If you add an implementation of `writeObject` which throws an exception, serialization will be aborted, e.g.

```
  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    throw new RuntimeException("Don't want to serialize today");
  }
```

See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/ for a good introduction to overriding the default serialization behaviour.

Comment: I would recommend throwing a more specific  `UnsupportedOperationException` instead of the general `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 3):

The three custom serialisation methods you want to provide are `writeObject`, `readObject` and `readObjectNoData`. The appropriate exception to throw is the appropriately named `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

```
private void writeObject(
    ObjectOutputStream out {
) throws IOException {
    throw new NotSerializableException();
}
private void readObject(
    ObjectInputStream in
) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    throw new NotSerializableException();
}
private void readObjectNoData( 
) throws ObjectStreamException {
    throw new NotSerializableException();
}
```

A little trick (though not actually specified in the spec) is to cause an NPE when the system attempts to create the matching `java.io.ObjectStreamClass`. I <3 `null`s.

```
private static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields = { null }
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

> Classes that require special handling during the serialization and deserialization process must implement special methods with these exact signatures:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

You could always try to overload the `writeObject` with the signature above, and throw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is available only for classes that implement [`Serializable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) (read the docs of this interface). I don't think you can switch it of at runtime. If you don't want objects to be serializable, don't make them implement `Serializable`.

If the serialization is within your control (i.e. you are calling `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(..)`), then just make a configuration option that will disallow that call.

Another option would be to implement the `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)` method of and throw an exception depending on a configuration option.